# Windows Batch File for loop on user dir

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I need to create a batchfile to delete a specific file in the users appdata dir. The batchfile is executed as localsystem.

I did test the following senarios:
Command Prompt as localsystem - this works
Command Prompt as admin - this works
Command Prompt as user - this works for all folders where the user has permissions

As soon as i put the for loop in a batch file, it dosent work anymore.
It also dosent matter in which context (User,admin,localsystem) i start it.

```
for /D %i in ("C:\Users\*") do del /Q /F "%i\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties"
```

The exit code shows 255, which means to long error.

The error i get is the following:

```
C:\Windows\Scripts>sync_exeptionsiteslistandconfig_java.bat > output.txt
\Users\*") do del "i\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties"  /Q /F was unexpected at this time.
```

Any help why the single line is working and a batchfile with this single line is not working is welcome.

Please also explain why it is not working. (I always run tasks as localsystem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may do what you want, but it only processes normal folders, not hidden etc.

Your problem may have been using %i within a batch script.

```
@echo off
for /D %%i in ("C:\Users\*") do del /Q /F "%%i\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties" 2>nul
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you very much, it works. But do you know why using %%i instead of %i? I could still not understand why it is working directly in a command prompt.

Comment: It's required in a batch file for loop to double the `%` signs.  At the cmd prompt only one `%` is used.